# Data augmentation to equilibrate class occurences on image set with multiple different objects in each image

Tags: object-detection, data-augmentation

I am using [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nomihsa965/large-scale-image-dataset-of-wood-surface-defects?resource=download-directory&select=Images%20-%201) (reduced) dataset to run tests for detection of defects in solid wood using YOLOV5. Initial tests are promising. As can be seen in Fig. 1, my class occurences are quite imbalanced - there are many instances of different knots, however the other classes are not very well represented. My results indicate that this is an issue for the classifier.

[image: Fig. 1: Statistics on labels]

How may I go about augmenting my dataset to equilibrate class occurences? My issue is that an image containing e. g. Marrow is also likely to contain knots. Thus by flipping/mirroring/scaling these images, I would also increase the occurencies of knots. I don't have the feeling that simple image transformations will resolve my issue.

Is it a viable option to crop out defects of inteterest (the underrepresented ones) along their mask and place them on images that only contain background? Or will this create artefacts on the mask boundaries?

Are there any other methods that would be applicable in my situation?